# Отправка письма из формы в битриксе

Tags: файлы, битрикс, события, sendmail

Недавно в битриксе. Решаю задачу, есть форма с полями EMAIL_PL и NAME_PL. В админке битрикса есть почтовый шаблон, и почтовое событие SEND_PRICE_LIST. Форма перенаправляет на страницу ajax/price-list-email.php. В нем пишу такой код:

```
require($_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]."/bitrix/modules/main/include/prolog_before.php");
use Bitrix\Main\Mail\Event;

     print_r($_POST);
     $arEventFields = array(
            "EMAIL_PL" => $_POST["EMAIL_PL"],
            "NAME_PL" => $_POST["NAME_PL"],
      );
          
      if (Event::send(array(
          "EVENT_NAME" => "SEND_PRICE_LIST",
          "LID" => "s1",
          "C_FIELDS" => $arEventFields,
      ))){
         echo "<b>Спасибо, Ваше сообщение успешно отправлено.</b>";  
      } else {
          echo "Ошибка отправки письма!";
      }
```

В шаблоне письма (почтовые шаблоны) прикрепляю к файл pdf и картинку. В итоге письмо приходит и там закодированная информация, а не файлы прикрепленные к письму.

> ---------mix659648039b Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8 Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit Информационное сообщение сайта
> auto.dev.studio.ru
> ------------------------------------------ На сайте auto.dev.studio.ru успешно сформировано письмо с
> прайс-листом для пользователя Андрей-нью Данные пользователя: E-Mail:
> integral@mail.ru Письмо сгенерировано автоматически.
> ---------mix659648039b Content-Type: application/pdf; name="=?UTF-8?B?S2luZW1QUFAucGRm?=" Content-Disposition: attachment;
> filename="=?UTF-8?B?S2luZW1QUFAucGRm?=" Content-Transfer-Encoding:
> base64 Content-ID: <6289>
> JVBERi0xLjQKJdDUxdgKMSAwIG9iago8PCAvUyAvR29UbyAvRCAoc2VjdGlvbi4xKSA+PgplbmRv
> YmoKNCAwIG9iagooXDM3NlwzNzdcMDA0XDAyMlwwMDRcMDYyXDAwNFwwNjVcMDA0XDA2NFwwMDRc
> MDY1XDAwNFwwNzVcMDA0XDA3MFwwMDRcMDY1KQplbmRvYmoKNSAwIG9iago8PCAvUyAvR29UbyAv
> RCAoc2VjdGlvbi4yKSA+PgplbmRvYmoKOCAwIG9iagooXDM3NlwzNzdcMDA0XDAzMlwwMDRcMDcz
> XDAwNFwwNjBcMDA0XDEwMVwwMDRcMTAxXDAwNFwwNzBcMDA0XDEwN1wwMDRcMDY1XDAwNFwxMDFc
> MDA0XDA3MlwwMDRcMDcwXDAwNFwwNjVcMDAwXDA0MFwwMDRcMDc0XDAwNFwwNjVcMDA0XDEwMlww
> MDRcMDc2XDAwNFwwNjRcMDA0XDExM1wwMDBcMDQwXDAwNFwwNzdcMDA0XDA3NlwwMDRcMDY3XDAw
> NFwwNzBcMDA0XDEwNlwwMDRcMDcwXDAwNFwwNzZcMDA0XDA3NVwwMDRcMDcwXDAwNFwxMDBcMDA0
> XDA3NlwwMDRcMDYyXDAwNFwwNjBcMDA0XDA3NVwwMD и.т.д.

Как исправить такое?